# Ionic 3 Loading Component not fullscreen

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, loading

When we use LoadingController in Ionic 3, it takes the fullscreen control.

Is it possible to create loading  screen just for an HTML element?
For Example I have 4 cards displayed in a page and each of them will show the loading until the data is loaded. In the mean time, rest of the elements should be available to the user.

I have tried to implement it but can not find help from Ionic 3 [Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#loading-controller)

I have tried custom loading with the following code but it did not work. It still takes the full screen.

TS page:

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `
      <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box"></div>
      </div>`,
    duration: 5000
  });

  loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed loading');
  });

  loading.present();
}
```

HTML page:

```
<div class="custom-spinner-container">
<div class="custom-spinner-box"> My content here...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: show how you've implemented to help you. Use http://stackblitz.com/.

Comment: Good question..